# Ubuntu 14 mouse single click registering/behaving as double click

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Since I upgraded my Ubuntu box to 14, I was facing the issue that almost every time a folder, item, etc was single clicked, it fire a double click action. As you can imagine this was very annoying, since I have to try it a couple of time every time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, since I couldn't find anything on the Internet tackling this issue, I started thinking of when it was first introduced and for some reason it came to me that it was when Canonical started merging some of the Ubuntu touch stuff with the normal release.

**The fix**

I just ***commented out*** the section about the *touchscreen* in the ***/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf*** and *rebooted it*.

```
#Section "InputClass"
#        Identifier "evdev touchscreen catchall"
#        MatchIsTouchscreen "on"
#        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
#        Driver "evdev"
#EndSection
```

Now the issue seems to be gone.

Hope this help someone else facing the same issue.